# Internet Explorer not supported jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have created website designing in html5,css,javascript and jquery. My page is working fine in `chrome` and `firebox`, but not working in `Internet Explorer`. First page is working fine in `IE`, but after clicking submenu of TBB it's not working.
TBB is using in form. click the TBB

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function TBBformOpen() {    
        jQuery("#TBB").css("display", "block");
    }
</script>
```

it jquery not supported in Internet Explorer.

Comment: what version of ie and what version of jquery?

Comment: describe any errors you see in the browsers developer tools console

Comment: SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x3, The system cannot find the path specified.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is only supported in Internet Explorer 9+, so if you're in an older version, you're out of luck perhaps, with a newer version. BUT... [taken from the jQuery site...](https://jquery.com/browser-support/)

> If you need to support older browsers like Internet Explorer 6-8, Opera 12.1x or Safari 5.1+, use jQuery 1.12.

So you will have to use 1.12 to get what you're working on to work.

Good luck!